# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm creating a record in MySQL and if it's already there I don't want to create it.  However I would like to update a field called `invite_state`, to mean that whatever the relation was, it now should go back to the state `INVITED`. The problem is there is one exception to this rule - if the state is `UNSUBSCRIBED` then it shouldn't go back to `INVITED`.

So this would be an `on duplicate key update` in MySQL but this doesn't support a `where` clause.  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use the `IF` statement.

```
insert into (...) values (...)
on duplicate key update
set invite_state = IF(where_condition, new_value, invite_state)
```